# Spring SpEL type conversion within expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I know SpEL is happy to attempt to convert a result into a requested type using Spring's `ConversionService` framework but I want it to work *within* the expression itself.

This simple snippets fails because it is comparing an `Enum` to a `String`...

```java
  ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(new SpelParserConfiguration(true, true));
  StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();

  parser.parseExpression("#this.myEnum == 'SOMETHING'")
    .getValue(context, myThing, Boolean.class);
```

... where this ugly expression would work ...

```
  #this.myEnum == T(com.my.package.MyEnum).SOMETHING
```

Spring knows very well how to convert between `String`<>`Enum` so is there a way to configure this to work inline.

Comment: Did you try this:  `'SOMETHING'== #this.myEnum`? Or in the end like this `#this.myEnum.name() == 'SOMETHING'`

Comment: First doesn't work, second does but the aim is to keep-it-simple. I know there are verbose ways to make it work (Enum is just a basic example) but I'd like Spring to use its muscles here instead of me.

Comment: Probably you expect too much and the mentioned `ConversionService` works only for the output value...